# Magento global configuration for multi store

Tags: magento

I would like to set up a magento website to sell pizzas, here are my specs:

- -I only have one domain name but several physicals stores which will
  be able to deliver the pizzas or
  authorize the customer to pick up his
  order directly at the store.
- -The user will have to type his postcode so that will be the nearest store which will handle his command (deliver or pick up, everything is transparent for the user).
- -The menu is the same for all the stores (so will be the root catalog), we do not care about stock, but a store can be out of an item (pizzas).
- -I will need a backend administration of stores property(adress/email/phone number) and a way to specify his delivering area (list of postcode or something).

I'm playing around with multisotre but it doesn't seems to fulfill all my expectations, any feedback from someones who has done the kind of same configuration ?
Is there some plugins that can be helpful here ? Which part will need lot of development ?Do you have good links about this? Which one of Multistore or multiwebsite is more convenient?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all steps just one trick. 
You should do a special landing page for store/area selecting then forward users related store what they select.

For instance, I can do interactive map of our stores which user can select easily nearest store.

Comment: so I guess your using multi store ? Can you customize store properties in the backend (adress,mail,location...)?

Comment: sure, you should select store first ( on top of left navigation bar in admin section ) then fill necessary settings.